# Strange behaviour observed in suspend-wrapped callback

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I've created the following to wrap the callback convention found in the [Stripe Kotlin/Java SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=android&reader-type=tap-to-pay#discover-readers):

```kotlin
suspend fun Terminal.discoverReaders(stripeTerminalConfiguration: DiscoveryConfiguration): List<Reader> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->

        discoverReaders(
            stripeTerminalConfiguration,
            object : DiscoveryListener {
                override fun onUpdateDiscoveredReaders(readers: List<Reader>) {
                    continuation.resume(readers)
                }
            },
            object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException) {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(e)
                }

                override fun onSuccess() {
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

What happens is I'm able to call it once.  But any subsequent attempt to call the method seems to just cause the flow of my application to mysteriously stop.  I've make sure I'm using coroutine scopes everywhere I attempt to invoke my `discoverReaders` extension method.  I've dropped breakpoints and log statements everywhere.  The moment that `discoverReaders` is called a second time, it's like my entire application logic halts, even though UI animations continue just fine??

[image]

Comment: I’ve never used this SDK, so just a hunch. Shouldn’t you be resuming your continuation from the `success` function in the Callback? That other listener looks like something that might be called multiple times.

Comment: From very briefly looking at the documentation, it seems like a success state won’t be reached until you connect to one of the users returned in the discovery listener. So maybe that’s what you should be trying to do in that listener, and then resume the continuation in `onSuccess`. Also, this should be in a  `suspendCancellableCoroutine` so you can tear down the callbacks if the coroutine is cancelled.

Comment: I think what’s happening is you are just returning  the first list returned to the listener and then never connect to one or whatever you need to do to resolve this `discoverReaders` task, and the SDK doesn’t support multiple parallel `discoverReaders` tasks. If you truly only want the readers, you should set this up as a non-suspend function returning a `Flow<List<Reader>>` using `callbackFlow` and properly use the internal `awaitClose` to tear it down. You can also cal `close()` in the `onSuccess()` part so the flow will automatically end when a Reader is connected.